# Appium Grid hub sending wrong set of capabilities to nodes

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-grid, appium-ios

I am trying to configure Appium Grid with below node configuration.

-Hub is receiving proper capabilities from testng but hub is sending wrong capabilities to my only two nodes. (node configs are as follows )

Please do suggest where am I going wrong.

### Emulator Node config

Command running the node with :  `node appium.js --port 4723 --nodeconfig G:\Selenium2\Grid\AppiumEmulatorNode.json`

```
{
    "capabilities": [{
        "browserName": "Emulator_5.1.0",
        "version": "5.1.0",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "platform": "ANDROID"
    }],
    "configuration": {
        "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
        "timeout": 30000,
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "url": "http://192.168.0.104:4723/wd/hub",
        "host": 192.168.0.104,
        "port": 4723,
        "maxSession": 1,
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "hubPort": 4444 ,
        "hubHost": "192.168.0.104"
    }
}
```

### Real device Node config

Command running the node with : `node appium.js --port 4724 --nodeconfig G:\Selenium2\Grid\AppiumRealDevice.json`

```
{
    "capabilities": [{
        "browserName": "Sony Xperia SP",
        "version": "5.1.1",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "platform": "ANDROID"
    }],
    "configuration": {
        "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
        "timeout": 30000,
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "url": "http://192.168.0.104:4724/wd/hub",
        "host": "192.168.0.104",
        "port": 4724,
        "maxSession": 1,
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "hubPort": 4444 ,
        "hubHost": "192.168.0.104"
    }
}
```

### Testng file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestsSuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2" verbose="5">

    <test name="Test1">
        <parameter name="UdidOrDeviceName" value="YT910LQ91K"></parameter>
        <parameter name="MobileVersion" value="5.2.0"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.apps.AppiumTest.AppiumMessengerTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2">
        <parameter name="UdidOrDeviceName" value="192.168.113.101:5555"></parameter>
        <parameter name="MobileVersion" value="5.1.0"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.apps.AppiumTest.AppiumMessengerTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

### Grid hub Output

```
   19:47:56.092 INFO - Registered a node http://192.168.0.104:4723
19:51:05.917 INFO - Registered a node http://192.168.0.104:4724
19:51:31.419 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{appActivity=com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList, appPackage=com.android.mms, platformVersion=5.2.0, newCOmmandTimeout=1000, platformName=Android, deviceName=YT910LQ91K}]
19:51:31.433 INFO - Available nodes: [http://192.168.0.104:4723, http://192.168.0.104:4724]
19:51:31.438 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{appActivity=com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList, appPackage=com.android.mms, platformVersion=5.1.0, newCOmmandTimeout=1000, platformName=Android, deviceName=192.168.113.101:5555}]
19:51:31.438 INFO - Trying to create a new session on node http://192.168.0.104:4723
19:51:31.460 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {maxInstances=3, platformName=ANDROID, deviceName=192.168.113.101:5555, version=5.1.0}
19:51:31.476 INFO - Available nodes: [http://192.168.0.104:4724, http://192.168.0.104:4723]
19:51:31.486 INFO - Trying to create a new session on node http://192.168.0.104:4724
19:51:31.501 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {browserName=Sony Xperia SP, maxInstances=1, version=5.1.1, platform=ANDROID}
```

### Emulator Node output

**This node receiving wrong set of data from Selenium Grid.It should receive emulator capabilities but it has received real device capabilities**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin>node appium.js --port 4723 --nodeconfig G:\Selenium2\Grid\AppiumEmulatorNode.json
info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"nodeconfig":"G:\\Selenium2\\Grid\\AppiumEmulatorNode.json"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: [debug] starting auto register thread for grid. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
info: [debug] Appium successfully registered with the grid on 192.168.0.104:4444
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 28.871 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 11.314 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList","appPackage":"com.android.mms","platformVersion":"5.2.0","newCOmmandTimeout":1000,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"YT910LQ91K"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_65)
```

### Real Device Node output

**This node receiving wrong set of data from Selenium Grid.It should receive Real device capabilities but it has received emulator capabilities**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin>node appium.js --port 4724 --nodeconfig G:\Selenium2\Grid\AppiumRealDevice.json
info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4724
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"port":4724,"nodeconfig":"G:\\Selenium2\\Grid\\AppiumRealDevice.json"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: [debug] starting auto register thread for grid. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
info: [debug] Appium successfully registered with the grid on 192.168.0.104:4444
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 22.103 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 12.602 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 11.690 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 11.460 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 11.927 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}}}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList","appPackage":"com.android.mms","platformVersion":"5.1.0","newCOmmandTimeout":1000,"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"192.168.113.101:5555"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_65)
info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : newCOmmandTimeout
info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 515cbed7-46c0-4fce-a2e0-652976c5a659
info: Starting android appium
info: [debug] Getting Java version
info: Java version is: 1.8.0_71
info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
info: [debug] Preparing device for session
info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
info: Retrieving device
info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
info: [debug] 2 device(s) connected
info: Found device 192.168.113.101:5555
info: [debug] Setting device id to 192.168.113.101:5555
info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 wait-for-device
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 shell "echo 'ready'"
info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
info: [debug] Getting device API level
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
info: [debug] Device is at API Level 22
info: Device API level is: 22
info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 push "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}},"sessionId":"515cbed7-46c0-4fce-a2e0-652976c5a659"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 69.204 ms - 156 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.16","revision":"ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d"}},"sessionId":"515cbed7-46c0-4fce-a2e0-652976c5a659"}
info: Starting App
info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
info: [debug] No matching processes found
info: [debug] Running bootstrap
info: [debug] spawning: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.android.mms -e disableAndroidWatchers false
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.IllegalStateException
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=UiAutomationService android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceClient$Stub$Proxy@1034d97calready registered!
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
info: [debug] UiAutomator exited
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Harsha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.113.101:5555 shell "echo 'ping'"
info: [debug] Attempting to uninstall app
info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched
info: [debug] Error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:205:23)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-hybrid.js:249:5)
    at Object.async.eachSeries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:142:20)
    at [object Object].androidHybrid.stopChromedriverProxies (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-hybrid.js:233:9)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:200:10)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:222:9)
    at [object Object].androidCommon.uninstallApp (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:478:5)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:220:12)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:229:11)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:901:7
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:180:9)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:194:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched)","origValue":"UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched"},"sessionId":null}
```

Comment: probably an adb instance not allocated for the UIAutomator to startup with, hence it would quit. Shall be solved upon restarting the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how the Grid decides to which node should a test be routed to.

It uses something called as a Capability Matcher, to help it decide as to which among its nodes should a test be routed to. If you don't provide a custom capability matcher [ You can take a look at [this blog](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/working-with-a-custom-capability-matcher-in-the-grid/) of mine to understand how to plugin in your own custom variant ], it resorts to relying on the [DefaultCapabilityMatcher](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/DefaultCapabilityMatcher.java#L56) for doing this matching job.

Since you haven't set any of the attributes that the default capability matcher understands [ see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/DefaultCapabilityMatcher.java#L41-L45) for learning what are those ], it always matches the first node with a test. That is why you are seeing the mess up.

It only understands [browserName](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.java#L24), [platform](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.java#L25), [version](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.java#L28) and [applicationName](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.java#L38) and for browserName, platform you cannot pass in any arbitrary values but can only use predefined values. See [BrowserType](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/BrowserType.java) and [Platform](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Platform.java) java classes.

So to solve your problem, you have two options.

Option 1 : You build your own capability matcher which suites your needs (you can refer to my blog post link that I have shared above) and work with it.

Option 2 : You resort to using the capability "applicationName" wherein you provide a unique value to this for each of your nodes and then rely on your test to add this extra capability at the test level.

That should resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Did not know this concept. With this I can completely differentiate between nodes easily.

Comment: @krishnan-mahadevan..Oops.forgot to accept it.Done now :)

Comment: applicationName is no more part of W3C and I am getting an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities: [applicationName]. Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue?